# How does this graph mean infinite velocity and acceleration?

Tags: kinematics

[image]

How does this graph tell us that the acceleration and velocity is infinite . I am not able to get it. I think both of them say finite velocity and acceleration.

Comment: Hint: $a=dv/dt$ and $v=ds/dt$.

Comment: It is not infinite everywhere, but some instants fo time are clearly singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph to the left shows a velocity that reduces at a constant rate then increases in no time at all. The instantaneous increase in velocity implies an infinite acceleration.

The graph to the right shows an increasing distance which then reduces in no time at all. A change in distance in zero time implies an infinite velocity.